# Simple WYSIWYG HTML editpart for eclipse rcp?

Tags: html, eclipse, editor, rcp

I am looking for a Eclipse plugin which I could use to provide a WYSIWYG HTML editor in an Eclipse RCP application.

I need nothing fancy, something with similar functionality to the editor I am using to type this question would be sufficient.

Based on the answers to [What is the best HTML editor for Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54868/1012875) there should be one provided by the [Web Tools Platform](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/) project: [Web Page Editor](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Web_Page_Editor). But I could not figure out its class name to use it inside a View.

A small code example on using it would be especially helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
Quick tutorial:
In eclipise:
-import project from cvs, host: dev.eclipse.org, repository path:/cvsroot/webtools, user:anonymous, connection type:pserver
-click next, find and choose plugin org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner and import it to your workspace
-create Hello RCP
-in plugin.xml tab extension add new: org.eclipse.ui.editor
-in this extension point add new element, editor and set: id- no matter what, but remember it for future (e.g. "editorId"), extensions: xml,html,xhtml class:org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner.editors.HTMLEditor, contributorClass: org.eclipse.jst.pagedesigner.editors.actions.PageDesignerActionBarContributor2, default: false.
-Now you have to open a file, "transform" to IEditorInput
-call method IWorkbenchPage.openEditor(iEditorInput,"editorId")
Should work!
```